# Update state values from a different file in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am keeping all my functions in one file, and calling those functions in activities where needed in my `react native` project. Now in one of my functions which has a `fetch api`, I am fetching data from my online server and printing the response after a successful query.

Now I want to be able to update `state` value with the response from the `fetch method` in the `then`.

```
 App.js

 ...


import {registerUsers} from './src/utils/api.js'


export class App extends Component{

state = {
    isLoggedIn:false,
    isLoading:false,
    isAppready:false
}


_Register = (email,password,fullName) =>{
    this.setState({isLoading:true})

   //calling the register user function here 
   registerUsers(email,password,fullName)
}

...
```

The api file

```
 import React from 'react'
 import { Alert } from 'react-native';


 export function registerUsers(email, password, fullName) {


fetch('http://00.00.00.00/reg/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    userEmail: email,

    userPassword: password,

    userFullName: fullName

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {


      //setState({ isLoggedIn: true, isLoading: false })
  // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
      Alert.alert(responseJson);


      }).catch((error) => {

         // this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true, isLoading: false })
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

I would now want to update the `state` values thus `isLoggedIn: true` and `isLoading:false` after the  `fetch method` has been processed. The problem now is that I can't figure it out where to update the `state` values since I am calling the `registerUsers` function from a different file.

I would be grateful if someone could share an idea as to how to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: You need to make use of Redux, to have a global state and can make it available to the required components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registerUsers` should return the promise. That way, you can handle the response directly inside your component:

API:

```
export function registerUsers(email, password, fullName) {

    return fetch('http://00.00.00.00/reg/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            userEmail: email,
            userPassword: password,
            userFullName: fullName
        })
    }).then( response => response.json());
}
```

Component:

```
import {registerUsers} from './src/utils/api.js'


export class App extends Component{

state = {
    isLoggedIn:false,
    isLoading:false,
    isAppready:false
}


_Register = (email,password,fullName) =>{
    this.setState({isLoading:true})

   //calling the register user function here 
   registerUsers(email, password, fullName)
       .then( responseJson => {
            this.setState({ 
                isLoggedIn: true, 
                isLoading: false,
                data: responseJson
            });
        }).catch( error => {
            this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false, isLoading: false });
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much for your time, this worked well for me